# Is there a difference in a degree of effort between "try to" and "try ing"?

Tags: infinitive-vs-gerund

according to [a grammar site](https://learnenglish.britishcouncil.org/grammar/b1-b2-grammar/verbs-followed-by-ing-or-by-to-infinitive-2)

Try + -ing means that you are trying something as an experiment, especially as a possible solution to a problem, to see if it works or not.

And

Try + to + infinitive means that something is difficult but you are making an effort to do it.

But in some posts like [a StackExchange post](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/146130/try-ing-vs-try-to-infinitive)

I can't find mention of a degree of effort.
In Korea, I've been taught to strictly distinguish two of them(by what "a grammar site" says), so it's confusing to me that they don't talk about a degree of effort.

Comment: You've written the same definition *twice*, where presumably you intended to show us ***two different definitions***  (one for ***try doing***, and one for ***try to do***). Please edit the post to correct this.

Comment: @FumbleFingers umm no, I intended to show you two different version of posts which compares try doing and try to do

Comment: Check your question text again. You've written *exactly* the same text in the two consecutive sentences starting with **Try + -ing means that...**

Comment: @FumbleFingers I edited the question

Comment: @FumbleFingers sorry, no

Comment: The difference between *He had a headache, so (1) he **tried taking** aspirin* and *...so (2) he tried **to take** aspirin* is nothing to do with "degree of effort". It's to do with "success" - in (1), he successfully took aspirin (which may or may not have cured the headache), but in (2) there's a strong implication that he wasn't even able to take aspirin.

Comment: Read the linked question again (more carefully than you read your *own* question! :) I'm sure StoneyB's answer *does* fully address your question.

Comment: @FumbleFingers Thank you. So you think the explanation of "a grammer site" is incorrect right?

Comment: I haven't followed your links, but this is such a well-known usage distinction I think you've probably misunderstood something. The point is you're obviously asking about the difference between ***try to do*** and ***try doing***, the same as hundreds of previous visitors to this site. And that difference is fully covered by an existing question and answer.

Comment: It's not clear what you want. You're talking about two forms of the same verb, but asking about meaning. They have the same meaning but the tense is different.

Comment: @Astralbee: No, they *don't* have the same meaning. As per OP's British Council link, ***try doing it*** means to do it in order to see if that fixes some problem, but ***try to do it*** means to make an effort to do it (there isn't necessarily even any "problem" that needs to be fixed).

Comment: ...and *try **and** do it* leads to the potential ambiguity of [Suspect: "Try and convict me." Prosecutor: "Have it your way. We'll try and convict you."](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/27024/2637)

Comment: @FumbleFingers The question has been edited almost 7 hours after my comment, which I stand by.

Comment: @Astralbee: OP's *first* change (made *before* your comment) was to correct the fact that he'd repeated the same definition. The only change made *since* your comment was to change the tag from **grammar** to **infinitive-vs-gerund**, so you can't really imply your comment was "valid at the time".

Answer (score 3):

Examples:

> [1] *You should try to eat less.*
>
> [2] *You should try eating less.*

Here, the infinitival and gerund-participial forms of "try" have a difference of meaning.

In [1] "try" means "endeavour"; in [2] "try" means "test the effectiveness of".